# API Tags - soap, rest, etc. or soap-api, rest-api, etc?

Tags: discussion, tags

This seems to be a good issue to nail down early... How do we tag questions about the respective apis? I propose `abc-api`, then we can use the bare `abc` tag for more general questions about that technology. For instance, tag questions specific to the Chatter API with `chatter-api`, and more general questions with just `chatter`.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

I think the fact that this needed a question means the proposed scheme is too complicated. I would propose just tagging "api" plus whatever the subject matter is - could be the type of API ("rest"), could be functional ("authentication"), etc.

If you have to educate people about which tags to use, you will lose.

Answer (score -1):

rest

- chatter-api (chatter tag already exists)
- rest-api* @superfell even though this doesn't make strict sense, it is what people think of when they're talking about the sobject-api
- identity-api

soap

- <strike>soap-api</strike> replaced with webservices-api (partner and enterprise)
- metadata-api
- streaming-api
- apex-api

*Existing tags

**Edit** collating the comments

Comment: Agreed - the bare 'soap' tag doesn't seem to make much sense unless it's a general question about, say, REST vs SOAP in the Force.com dev community.

Comment: and if the question was REST vs SOAP I would probably down vote it as not being constructive

Comment: Yeah - as I was typing that I was thinking 'Hmm - that's a survey-type question' :-)

Comment: I would say soap-api should instead be webservices-api to disambiguate it from the technology.

Comment: Regarding soap-api, that was my first thought too, but seeing as the soap-api tag is already being used. That horse may have already bolted

Comment: rest-api & soap-api don't make sense, in rest there's the sobject api, the chatter api and the identity api, in soap there's enterprise, partner, metadata & apex apis.

Comment: @superfell Most of the outside world knows the sobject API as the 'REST API'. Our doc writers seem to agree with them: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/index.htm. Similarly for the SOAP API http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm.