# apex-* tags discussion

Tags: discussion, tags

The question [API Tags](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/api-tags-soap-rest-etc-or-soap-api-rest-api-etc) got me thinking. What is the organisation of *apex-** tags going to look like. Not surprisingly the [apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apex) tag already exists, but what about more specific tags, here are some suggestions I can think of:

- apex-rest: for @RestResource classes
- apex-batch
- apex-schedulable

I am sure there are heaps more.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't think creating merged tags like this will add any value. Instead it will be better if we add 2 separate tags. So instead of apex-rest, use `apex` and `rest`.

This will also help members who like to subscribe to individual tags, and also avoid creating new tags (with weird annotations like apex-workflow) when 2 separate tags can do the job. That's my 2 cents anyway.

Anup

Comment: Agreed. I think we want to avoid creating hierarchies and complicated taxonomies since tags were created specifically to avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I agree with you both on the matter.

Comment: Agree with this 100%. `batch` would be another prime candidate as any apex developer will know what it consists of.

Comment: Agreed, and let me put it another way: As a member of the apex code dev team, I keep a browser tab open to http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apex?page=1&sort=newest     <-- very convenient ;)