# Should we make/allow tags for specific Visualforce tags?

Tags: discussion

Today I asked a [question about working with `<apex:tabPanel>`](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3874/alternative-layout-for-tabpanel).  It occured to me that (when appropriate), it could be useful to tag questions with tags specific to visualforce elements, but that might be overkill since users can also just search for "apex:tabPanel" or whatever they're looking for help on.

Possible syntax could be:

- vf-apex-tabPanel
- visualforce-apex-tabPanel
- apex-tabPanel
- tabPanel

What do you think?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that's too much. As you say, users can search for specific data they are interested.

I can see how Programers.SE will have such tags for each language or variable.

It might be good to add the element in the subject, but tag-per-element is an over kill.

Comment: I was leaning in this direction, too, but wanted to raise the question.  Good stuff!

Comment: Agreed - the visualforce tag is enough.

Answer (score 1):

I asked [a question](https://salesforce.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6/apex-tags-discussion) about this a while ago in regards to apex tags. The response there was similar: keep it simple, and avoid hierarchical tags